# How to create main.py file for Discord commands

Tags: discord, discord.py, command, bots, chatbot

I'm making a Discord bot that allows the user to play the mines gambling mini game and some other types of casino games. I want there to be individual files for each command, for example I have mines_game.py for the mines game and gambling_bot.py just for a simple coin flip (for testing mainly). I want to now make a main.py file that I can run the discord bot on that will allow the user to use BOTH the command for the coin flip and mines game. However when I try this it only runs the mines_game.py file I even tried running just the gambling_bot.py file and it still just runs the mines_game file can anyone help me fix this and help me make a proper main.py file

**mines_game.py**

```
import discord
import random
import keys
from discord.ext import commands
import keys
from keys import *

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

# Create a dictionary to keep track of the grid squares for each user
games = {}

# Define the command for creating the grid
print("Running mines_game.py")
@bot.command()
async def mines(ctx):
    # Check if the user has an existing game
    message_id = games.get(ctx.author.id)
    if message_id:
        # Check if the game is over
        if games[ctx.author.id].get('game_over', False):
            # Build the grid message
            grid_message = ':black_large_square:  A     B      C      D       E\n'
            for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                row = [f'{number} ']
                for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                    row.append(':blue_square:')
                grid_message += '   '.join(row) + '\n'
            # Send the message
            message = await ctx.send(grid_message)
            games[ctx.author.id] = {
                'message_id': message.id,
                'grid': {},
                'game_over': False
            }
            # Initialize the grid dictionary for the user
            for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                    games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number] = {
                        'status': ':blue_square:',
                        'updated': False
                    }
        else:
            # Edit the user's previous message
            message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message_id)
            # Build the grid message
            grid_message = ':black_large_square:  A     B      C      D       E\n'
            for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                row = [f'{number} ']
                for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                    row.append(games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number]['status'])
                grid_message += '   '.join(row) + '\n'
            await message.edit(content=grid_message)
    else:
        # Build the grid message
        grid_message = ':black_large_square:  A     B      C      D       E\n'
        for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
            row = [f'{number} ']
            for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                row.append(':blue_square:')
            grid_message += '   '.join(row) + '\n'
        # Send the message
        message = await ctx.send(grid_message)
        games[ctx.author.id] = {
            'message_id': message.id,
            'grid': {},
            'game_over': False
        }
        # Initialize the grid dictionary for the user
        for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
            for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number] = {
                    'status': ':blue_square:',
                    'updated': False
                }
# Define the command for updating a grid square
@bot.command(aliases=['u'])
async def update(ctx, *squares: str):
    # Check if the game has ended
    if games.get(ctx.author.id, {}).get('game_over', False):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} The game has ended! Use !mines to play again.")
        return

    # Check if the user has an existing game
    message_id = games.get(ctx.author.id, {}).get('message_id')
    if not message_id:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} You haven't initiated a mines game yet!")
        return

    # Initialize the grid dictionary for the user if not already initialized
    if 'grid' not in games[ctx.author.id]:
        games[ctx.author.id]['grid'] = {}
        for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
            for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number] = {
                    'status': ':blue_square:',
                    'updated': False
                }

    # Update the grid squares
    for square in squares:
        # Convert the square string to uppercase
        square = square.upper()

        # Check that the square is valid
        if square[0] not in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] or square[1] not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Invalid square '{square}'!")
            continue

        # Check if the square has already been updated
        if games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][square]['updated']:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} You can only update a square once!")
            continue

        # Mark the square as updated
        games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][square]['updated'] = True

        # Randomly determine if the square has a mine or not
        if random.random() < 0.2:
            games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][square]['status'] = ':bomb:'
            games[ctx.author.id]['game_over'] = True
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} You hit a bomb ): Use !mines to play again")
        else:
            games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][square]['status'] = ':green_square:'

    # Edit the grid message
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    grid_message = ':black_large_square:  A     B      C      D       E\n'
    for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
        row = [f'{number} ']
        for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
            row.append(games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number]['status'])
        grid_message += '   '.join(row) + '\n'
    await message.edit(content=grid_message)
     
bot.run(BOTTOKEN)
```

**Gambling_bot.py**

```
import discord
import random
import mines_game
from discord.ext import commands
from keys import *

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
intents.messages = True  # add this line to enable the message content intent

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!flip'):
        odds = 0.1  # set the default odds of landing on heads to 10%
        content = message.content.split()  # split the message into words
        if len(content) > 1:  # if a second word is provided
            try:
                odds = float(content[1])  # attempt to convert the word to a float
            except ValueError:
                pass  # ignore the word if it cannot be converted
        if random.random() < odds:  # if a random float between 0 and 1 is less than the odds
            result = 'heads'
        else:
            result = 'tails'
        await message.channel.send('The coin landed on {}!'.format(result))

client.run(BOTTOKEN)
```

**Please help me make a main.py file from this.**

I tried running just the gambling_bot.py file and it still just runs the mines_game i tried making my own main.py file but it still just only runs the mines.py file. I once ran the main.py file and was able to have it do the !flip (basically executing the code in gambling_bot.py) but then all the code from mines_game.py didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that `client.run()` will continue running forever. So your code takes the file that is imported first and runs that version forever, thus never running the second one.

There are two ways of fixing that:

1. "Merging" the two files
2. The Discord intended way: use cogs. With that you would be able to import commands from other files and have useful functions that allow you to deactivate one feature for example.

For the second way, make this (add all the needed imports in each file of course):

**main.py**

```py
from mines_game import mines_cog
from Gambling_bot import gambling_cog

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

asyncio.run(bot.add_cog(mines_cog()))
asyncio.run(bot.add_cog(gambling_cog(bot)))
```

**mines_game.py**

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

games = {}

class mines_cog(commands.Cog):
    @commands.command()
    async def mines(self, ctx):
        # Check if the user has an existing game
        message_id = games.get(ctx.author.id)
        if message_id:
            # Check if the game is over
            if games[ctx.author.id].get('game_over', False):
                # Build the grid message
                grid_message = ':black_large_square:  A     B      C      D       E\n'
                for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                    row = [f'{number} ']
                    for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                        row.append(':blue_square:')
                    grid_message += '   '.join(row) + '\n'
                # Send the message
                message = await ctx.send(grid_message)
                games[ctx.author.id] = {
                    'message_id': message.id,
                    'grid': {},
                    'game_over': False
                }
                # Initialize the grid dictionary for the user
                for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                    for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                        games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number] = {
                            'status': ':blue_square:',
                            'updated': False
                        }
            else:
                # Edit the user's previous message
                message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message_id)
                # Build the grid message
                grid_message = ':black_large_square:  A     B      C      D       E\n'
                for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                    row = [f'{number} ']
                    for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                        row.append(games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number]['status'])
                    grid_message += '   '.join(row) + '\n'
                await message.edit(content=grid_message)
        else:
            # Build the grid message
            grid_message = ':black_large_square:  A     B      C      D       E\n'
            for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                row = [f'{number} ']
                for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                    row.append(':blue_square:')
                grid_message += '   '.join(row) + '\n'
            # Send the message
            message = await ctx.send(grid_message)
            games[ctx.author.id] = {
                'message_id': message.id,
                'grid': {},
                'game_over': False
            }
            # Initialize the grid dictionary for the user
            for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                    games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number] = {
                        'status': ':blue_square:',
                        'updated': False
                    }
    # Define the command for updating a grid square
    @commands.command(aliases=['u'])
    async def update(self, ctx, *squares: str):
        # Check if the game has ended
        if games.get(ctx.author.id, {}).get('game_over', False):
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} The game has ended! Use !mines to play again.")
            return

        # Check if the user has an existing game
        message_id = games.get(ctx.author.id, {}).get('message_id')
        if not message_id:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} You haven't initiated a mines game yet!")
            return

        # Initialize the grid dictionary for the user if not already initialized
        if 'grid' not in games[ctx.author.id]:
            games[ctx.author.id]['grid'] = {}
            for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                    games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number] = {
                        'status': ':blue_square:',
                        'updated': False
                    }

        # Update the grid squares
        for square in squares:
            # Convert the square string to uppercase
            square = square.upper()

            # Check that the square is valid
            if square[0] not in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] or square[1] not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Invalid square '{square}'!")
                continue

            # Check if the square has already been updated
            if games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][square]['updated']:
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} You can only update a square once!")
                continue

            # Mark the square as updated
            games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][square]['updated'] = True

            # Randomly determine if the square has a mine or not
            if random.random() < 0.2:
                games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][square]['status'] = ':bomb:'
                games[ctx.author.id]['game_over'] = True
                await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} You hit a bomb ): Use !mines to play again")
            else:
                games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][square]['status'] = ':green_square:'

        # Edit the grid message
        message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message_id)
        grid_message = ':black_large_square:  A     B      C      D       E\n'
        for number in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:
            row = [f'{number} ']
            for letter in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']:
                row.append(games[ctx.author.id]['grid'][letter + number]['status'])
            grid_message += '   '.join(row) + '\n'
        await message.edit(content=grid_message)
```

**Gambling_bot.py**

```py
from mines_game import mines_cog
from Gambling_bot import gambling_cog

class pj_commands(commands.Cog):
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.content.startswith('!flip'):
            odds = 0.1  # set the default odds of landing on heads to 10%
            content = message.content.split()  # split the message into words
            if len(content) > 1:  # if a second word is provided
                try:
                    odds = float(content[1])  # attempt to convert the word to a float
                except ValueError:
                    pass  # ignore the word if it cannot be converted
            if random.random() < odds:  # if a random float between 0 and 1 is less than the odds
                result = 'heads'
            else:
                result = 'tails'
            await message.channel.send('The coin landed on {}!'.format(result))
```